# When overriding an ActiveRecord Model, and defining a new attr_accessible, how do I add without duplicating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, overriding, rails-engines

When I am using a Rails Engine, and desiring to override and add to its behavior, I have faced the following problem:

Say the Engine has a ActiveRecord model named Course

```
module MyEngine
  class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :description, :price

  end
end
```

And I want to create a migration in my main Rails app, to add a column to it, and I need to add that new column to the attr_accessible (so it can be mass assigned)

```
MyEngine::Course.class_eval do
  attr_accessible :expiration_date
end
```

But then Rails complains that the first 3 attrs are not Mass-Assignable, so instead of just "adding" the new attribute to the override, I have to re-declare all the attributes in the overridden class, like:

```
MyEngine::Course.class_eval do 
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :price, :expiration_date
end
```

Is there a better way to not re-declare these attributes, and just add the new attribute?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source code:

```
# File activemodel/lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb, line 174
def attr_accessible(*args)
  options = args.extract_options!
  role = options[:as] || :default

  self._accessible_attributes = accessible_attributes_configs.dup

  Array.wrap(role).each do |name|
    self._accessible_attributes[name] = self.accessible_attributes(name) + args
  end

  self._active_authorizer = self._accessible_attributes
end
```

You could try to use one of the internal data structures to recover the attributes that have already been defined, so you don´t duplicate code, or you can hack your way and create a new method that let´s you "append" values to attr_accessible. But there is no code baked for that yet.